# split a string by commas, but commas in a token

Tags: regex, parsing, rust, split

Let's say I have this:

```
something,"another thing"
```

This can be split easily with a normal split function.

Now I want to have more complicated syntax and I do:

```
something,"in a string, oooh",rgba(4,2,0)
```

This does not work with a regular split function.

I tried using things like replacing commas inside of specific types of tokens, but that became too over-complicated and I feel there has to be a better way.

Then I tried with regular expressions, which worked, until I had to add a new feature, which wouldn't work with the regexp I had (which was pretty bad), also regexp matches can be slow, and this is supposed to be as fast as possible.

What would be a better way to solve this?

Here is the source repo for extra context https://github.com/hyprland-community/hyprparse
And the format in question is the hyprland config format

Comment: For your second example, I assume you'd like to get `something`, `"in a string, oooh"` and `rgba(4,2,0)`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes! Exactly like that!

Comment: You may want to try a parser generator (see https://lib.rs/parsing for a list). I used `combine`, and was happy with it, but I am not sure if it is the most used one.

Comment: Can you maybe post the full format you'd like to recognize? Is it always three things in a row, where the first is characters, followed by something between quotation marks, and then a color value? Or are there more things to consider? Also: What regexp did you use?

Comment: Also, are you in control of the format? Because if so, what you have is very close to CSV. If you just decide to make it CSV (by putting your rgba field in quotes), then you can just use a CSV parser.

Comment: @phimuemue if it's just dquotes and commas, and you don't want to use csv for whaever reason, it's pretty easy to handroll the split as well.

Comment: Sadly im not in control of the format, the format is the format used by hyprland, here is the current source https://github.com/hyprland-community/hyprparse, and the regexp used `(?P<token>.+deg|rgba?\(.*?\)|".*?"|[^,]*)(?:,?|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the string keeping a context state:

1. None
2. Inside a "..."
3. Inside a (...)

Inside a context, comma has no separator meaning.

**Limitations**: This is a midnight hack!

See also [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b9308985ed3b06c4ff9e2226ffe5b067)

```rust
fn split(s: String) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut context = None;
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut start = 0;
    let mut items = Vec::new();
    
    for c in s.chars() {
        if context == Some('"') {
            if c == '"' {
                context = None;
            }
            i = i+1;
            continue;
        } else if context == Some('(') {
            if c == ')' {
                context = None;
            }
            i = i+1;
            continue;
        }
        
        if c == '"' || c == '(' {
            context = Some(c);
        }
        
        if c == ',' && context.is_none() {
            items.push(s[start..i].to_string());
            start = i + 1;
        }
        
        i = i+1;
    }
    items.push(s[start..i].to_string());
    items
}


fn main() {
    let s = "something,\"in a string, oooh\",rgba(4,2,0)".to_string();
    println!("{:?}", split(s));
    // -> ["something", "\"in a string, oooh\"", "rgba(4,2,0)"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help everyone, I eventually came up with my own solution with the help of people I knew IRL, here is my solution:

```rust
fn previous_rgb(index: usize, chars: Vec<char>) -> bool {
    let string: String = chars[index-3..index].iter().collect();
    let string = string.as_str();
    if string == "gba" || string == "rgb" {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}

fn splitter<Str: ToString>(s: Str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut is_in_rgb = false;
    let mut is_in_str = false;
    let mut last = 0;
    let chars: Vec<_> = s.to_string().chars().collect();
    let mut final_str = vec![];
    for (index, c) in chars.iter().enumerate() {
        if *c == '(' && previous_rgb(index, chars.clone()) && !is_in_str {
            is_in_rgb = true;
        } else if *c == ')' && is_in_rgb && !is_in_str {
            is_in_rgb = false;
        } else if *c == '"' && is_in_str {
            is_in_str = false;
        } else if *c == '"' && !is_in_str {
            is_in_str = true;
        } else if *c == ',' && !is_in_str && !is_in_rgb {
            final_str.push(chars[last..index].iter().collect());
            last = index + 1
        };
    }
    final_str.push(chars[last..].iter().collect());
    final_str
}

fn main() {
    let splitted = splitter(r#"test,test: rgba(5,4,3),"test2, seperated""#);
    println!("{splitted:?}");
}
```